# Prepocessor (Less) - Variável @Arguments

Tags: css, less, preprocessador

Supondo que tenho o seguinte mixin com seguintes argumentos:

```
.font-style(@size: 1.2em, @style: 100, @leading:1.4em, @color: #efefed)
```

Agora quero jogar esse mixin passando os arguntos que defino pra uma classe especifica. Ex:

```
.myClass{ .font-style(2.2em,...) }
```

**Dúvida**: Se quero modificar apenas o argumento **@size** e **@color**, seria necessário eu repetir os default (@arguments) por conta da ordem Ex:

`.font-style( @==a -> "mudei valor", @==b "default", @==c "default", @==d -> "mudei valor )`

Ou tem uma forma diferente que possa usar os default sem repetilos e mudar o que realmente necessito?

Answer (score 1):

Sim, quando criar seu mixin com parâmetros usando a variável "@arguments" deve explicitar um valor default para cada um deles.

Assim quando chamar seu mixin não precisa passar os valores em uma ordem especial e até mesmo omitir os defaults. Ex:

**Set Mixin**

```
.font-style(@size: 1.2em, @style: 100, @leading:1.4em, @color: #efefed);
```

**Call Mixin**

```
.myClass{ .font-style(2.2em,2.4em) }
```

Perceba omissão dos demais parâmetros.

Parâmetros opcionais (valor não explicito) necessitam ser passados quando houver a chamada. Ex:

```
.font-style(@size: @size, @color: @color);
```

Fontes:
https://github.com/SomMeri/less4j/wiki/Less-Language-Mixins#explicit-parameters
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116082/less-mixin-with-optional-parameters
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10837085/less-css-with-optional-parameters